# How to set icons on gnome shell message tray bar same size?

Tags: gnome-3, gnome-shell

My system is newest version archlinux, and WM is gnome3, everything is fine, but icon size of gnome shell message tray bar is not same, this seems ugly like follow pic:
[image]

And I have tried to change my "/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css", but have not locate the key to control the size of tray icon.

So is anybody knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682242). Gnome developers have been discussing the solution for over a year.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that stackoverflow is meant to be about programming, not tech support.